# Accidentally deleted public folder in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-backpack

Hi I was working on a project in Laravel using Backpack for my admin panel and today I deleted my project's public folder accidentally.

Fortunately I had backup at my GitHub repository and I have copy pasted the public folder from there. But After pasting, now my project is running index.php at public but not using backpack's  bootstrap and style sheets and other files. what I am doing wrong.

I am worried that I have lost my whole project. Please help to recover this problem. I have to submit my project tomorrow. Help please

[You can see it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V4zq.jpg)

Comment: Can you please check if CSS files are still there in public folder? Also check the permissions as well.

Comment: yes css files are there. But may be there is a problem with backpack's files. The interfaces which are outside backpack are using css but not backpack's admin panel. :(

Comment: I don't think stack-overflow is good site to ask questions. every time you ask a question and you are down voted quickly and there comes a time when stack-overflow do not allow you to ask more questions due to big number of down votes. disappointed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like you're probably missing the amdinlte assets that were published when you installed Backpack. Most likely, the version of your `public` folder that you recovered from your github repo is outdated and from before you installed Backpack therefore does't contain these assets.

I expect your browser console is complaining a lot about this if you check.

To fix this, try running the below:

- for version 4 of Backpack `php artisan backpack:install`
- or, for earlier versions `php artisan backpack:base:install`

Answer (score -1):

Try visiting the page within your browser and viewing the source within Chrome and clicking on the link (either src or href) within the tags for them and see if it brings you to the file.

If yes - clear your cache
If no - fix the links

Comment: I have tried to clear cache using "php artisan cache:clear" command. but the result is same. The links are also present but in the console I can see alot of errors showing that files are not found. I have check and found that files are actually not there ..so now I have no clue how to get files back. Can I get files from backpack? what is the option now?